# Page curl - Android 6 - Appcelerator titanium

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium, page-curl

I guys !
I work on app and I need a page curl for android 6, but, I don't find a good module...
Here are the sources I have already observed :

- http://gitt.io/component/com.visusway.mod.curlpageflip
- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/…

Do you have an idea ? advise on? Example?
Thank you very much !

Comment: - http://gitt.io/component/ti.pageflip
- https://github.com/adrianopaladini/FlipBook-Titanium
- https://github.com/leebourne/FlipBook-Titanium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this solution : https://github.com/manumaticx/TiAndroidFlip
Not really what I wanted.